# Android- Application Settings Force Stop

Tags: android

I didn't use any services in my application and closing the application by using

```
this.finish();
```

but my application still not stopped properly and it is running in background.when i go to application settings the force stop button is still enabled.

kindly share your views on proper exit of android application.

Comment: Paste error log please

Comment: Be sure you know the difference between an application and an activity in case you don't. @BrijeshThakur What error log? There's no error or crash to report.

Comment: There is no error log. @SK9 one or more activity constitutes the application right? so im using this.finish() in last activity. but still its not closed properly!!

Comment: Apps can loosely be thought of as a collection of activities, but that's very loose. "Apps" can share activities with each other for instance. Anyway, this is getting off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible you have another activity around.

From the Android docs, see `Activity.finish()`:

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The
>   ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via
>   onActivityResult().

There's no promise made that the activity will be closed right away on calling `finish()`, only that this is something that should be done. Usually this does happen right away, but without seeing your project I cannot comment further.

Note that Android, unlike iOS, doesn't really have a well-defined notion of an app. "Apps" can share activities and so on. For example it's not hard, but it's also non-trivial, for an "app" to know that it will go to background or that it has resumed.

Comment: If im using 5 activities , should i have to use in all the activities or is it enough to use it in the last i.e the 5 th activity.

Comment: However you do it, all activities would have to be finished.